# Change encoding of a file with grails

Tags: grails, encoding, utf-8, groovy

In my view i have a upload form:

```
<input type="file" name="file" value="search file" /><br />
```

In my controller I load it like that:

```
def file = request.getFile('file')
def f = file.getInputStream()
def input = f.getText()
```

So I have now a String called input with the content of the file.

I want it in UTF-8. How is this possible ?

Edit:

My problem is, that the file to be uploaded is in "Windows-1252" and German characters like äöü are different now in the string called "input".
If i convert the file with "Notepad++" in UTF-8 and then upload it, it works. But I cant do that every time.

Edit2:

```
def file = request.getFile('file')                      //get file from view
def File tmpfile = new File('C:/tmp/tmpfile.txt')       //create temporary file
file.transferTo(tmpfile)                                //copy into tmpfile
CharsetToolkit toolkit = new CharsetToolkit(tmpfile)    //toolkit with tmpfile
def charset = toolkit.getCharset()                      //save charset in a variable
def input = tmpfile.getText(charset)                    //get text with right charset
```

I tried this with a few different documents. But the variable charset is always `UTF_8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

I used java-bib called jUniversalChardet and wrote the following method:

```
String getEncoding ( def inputstream ) {
    def byte[] buf = new byte[4096]

    def UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null)

    def nread
    while ((nread = inputstream.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
      detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread)
    }
    detector.dataEnd();

    def encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset()

    return encoding
}
```

In my code i have the following now:

```
def file = request.getFile('file')
def f = file.getInputStream()
def encoding = getEncoding(file.getInputStream())
def input = f.getText(encoding)
```

And it works :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`getText(String charset)`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html#getText%28java.lang.String%29)

```
def input = f.getText('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Or you might be able to wrap the InputStream `def input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( file.getInputStream(), "UTF-8") ).text`

Comment: Doesnt work with my problem. I edited the description.

Comment: In that case, follow tim_yates approach. @user2244536

Comment: Doenst work either. A ä is a � after the upload. But if i convert with Notepad++ to UTF-8 it works fine. How can i implement that convert in my Conroller?

Comment: Works for me using both the approaches (Tim's and my). [Example](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6832581/). Gives the expected result.

Comment: @user2244536, use `f.getText('Windows-1252')` if file in Windows-1252 encoding

Comment: For testing I did an output of the input-String:

`def File output = new File("C:/tmp/xxx.txt") output << input` but in that file there are the �.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov that worked thanks. But if i dont know what type the input file has?

Comment: Use [`CharsetToolkit`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/CharsetToolkit.html) to guess the charset of a file. @user2244536

Comment: @dmahapatro How can I convert my multipartfile "file" to a standard File?

Comment: @dmahapatro i saw in an other forum how to convert and tried it but it fails. Watch description...